# console application works only from vs2010

Tags: c#, log4net

I wrote a console application project.

When I debug it through visual studio 2010 it runs and performs as needed.

When I run its exe from the cmd,

I don't see the log4net that (are redirected to the console)

No errors are shown on the console

The DB isn't updated.

What can cause this?

32bit proccess vs. 64?

My build is to 32bit.

I run on win7 with VS2010  dotNet 4

**update:**

My exe works.

but I cannot attach-to-it via visual studio

Log4net doesn't show logs to the console

this is my config file btw

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
    <section name="DBSubscriptionStorageConfig"
         type="NServiceBus.Config.DBSubscriptionStorageConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ToolbarsDB" connectionString="server=DEV-DBSRV50;database=TOOLBARSDB;PASSWORD=toolbarsapp;UID=toolbarsapp" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>


  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
          <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
          <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      <level value="INFO" />
          <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
          <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      <level value="ERROR" />
          <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
          <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      <level value="FATAL" />
          <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
          <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="log.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" xmlns="">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>

  <!--Publisher-->
  <DBSubscriptionStorageConfig>
    <NHibernateProperties>
      <add Key="connection.provider"
           Value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
      <add Key="connection.driver_class"
           Value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver"/>
      <add Key="connection.connection_string"
           Value="Data Source=DEV-DBSRV80;Initial Catalog=CPServicesDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=CPServicesDBUser;Password=oire^3jd!"/>
      <add Key="dialect"
           Value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect"/>
    </NHibernateProperties>
  </DBSubscriptionStorageConfig>
  <!-- End Publisher-->

  <appSettings>
    <add key="assemblyName" value="Conduit.CPServices.Logic.Bundlator"/>
    <add key="typeName" value="Conduit.CPServices.Logic.Bundlator.BundlatorMessageHandlers"/>
  </appSettings>

  <runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="AA95F207798DFDB4" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.4000" newVersion="3.2.0.4000"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CPServicesGeneralServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you try to launch it from a PowerShell console instead of the old cmd ?

Comment: can you paste the code where you configure log4net?

Comment: I think the log4net will help me better understand. What's wrong with my log4net congif?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you do not see the output when you run the application in `Command Prompt`, but it works fine in `Debug Mode`.

Are you reading the settings from a `app.config` by any chance? Maybe you need to copy the `Application XML Configuration File` as well as the `Executable`.

The file is normally called `MyApplication.exe.config`.

Comment: Already checked this. app.config is identical to the myApp.exe.config file

Comment: How do you call your app in console? Could you post the command? My guess is that maybe your working directory and directory with executable could be different.

Comment: I think the log4net will help me better understand. What's wrong with my log4net congif?